# DOMDocument Check if html code is in <h2> tag

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I have a function that get all `<h2>` using `DOMDocument`,
Now I want to check if there is any HTML tag between `<h2>[here]</h2>`, don't get the `<h2>` and skip to next.

My Code:

```
    foreach ($DOM->getElementsByTagName('*') as $element) {
       if ($element->tagName == 'h2') {
         $h = $element->textContent;
        }
     }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest thing is to just reuse `getElementsByTagName("*")` on the element and count how many items are found.

```php
$html = <<<EOT
<html><body><h2>Hello</h2> <h2>World</h2><h2><strong>!</strong></h2></body></html>
EOT;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('h2') as $h2) {
    if(!count($h2->getElementsByTagName('*'))){
        var_dump($h2->textContent);
    }
}
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/dI1e4

Comment: Yes, It's work. I add it like this: `if ($element->tagName == 'h2' && !count($element->getElementsByTagName('*')))`